# Most simple procedure for generating a set of orthogonal polynomials

Tags: orthogonality

I'm trying to reproduce the results of a paper. Somewhere (to explain a step of a procedure) the authors say:

> Generate a set of orthogonal polynomials with the square of the
> Ground-state wave function as the weight function (WF) adopting any of
> the standard algorithms

Now I have the ground state wave function (GSWF) but I don't know how to use the above step and generate a set of orthogonal polynomials using the GSWF? I googled Orthogonal Polynomials and I just understood that it is possible to generate a set of orthogonal polynomials using Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization for example, but I didn't understand how do so by my GSWF. If consider GSWF as $\psi_{gs}$ can anyone give me a simple procedure to generate a set of orthogonal polynomial with $\psi_{gs}$ as weight functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gram-schmidt is used to orthonormalise a group of vectors. You can't generate orthonormal vectors using gram-schmidt out of just a single vector.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Thanks a lot. I must use GSWF as weight function. So what is the appropriate method for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your given function as a starting point, you could generate first a set of complete functions. Let your weight function be $\phi^2_{gs}(x)$. We then construct the following set

$$S = \{x^n\phi^2_{gs}(x):n \in N\}$$

And now you can orthonormalise this set to get your orthogonal basis.

Comment: Thanks, Is it arbitrary to generate $S$ using $x^n$? After that should I apply gram-schmidt to $S$?

Comment: It's just easy to do it.. check https://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/documents/wi4006/orthopoly.pdf

Comment: Ok, Thanks again